# Preventing router.back() from navigating to external URLs outside of the app in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-router

I'm working on a Next.js application and I'm using the next/router module for client-side routing. In a specific scenario, I want to prevent the use of router.back() if it would lead to an external URL outside of my application's scope. Instead, I want to redirect the user to the homepage.

I'm looking for a way to check if the router.back() function would navigate to an external URL, so I can handle the redirection accordingly. I've explored the Next.js router documentation, but I couldn't find a direct method or property that provides this information.

Is there a way to determine if the router.back() function would lead to an external URL? If not, what approach or alternative solution can I use to achieve this behavior?

Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  const handleBack = () => {
    // Check if router.back() would lead to an external URL
    // If yes, redirect to the homepage
    // If no, perform the normal back navigation

    // Rest of the logic
  };

  // Rest of the component code
};
```

Any guidance or suggestions on how to handle this scenario would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Isn't it now considered poor UI/UX to trap users on your page/app?

Comment: Yeah its a trap but I think its necessary in my case. I'm working on a Next.js application where I want to implement conditional redirection upon login based on different scenarios. Specifically, I want to redirect the user to the same page they were viewing if they initiated the login process while navigating within our website. However, if the /login page is accessed directly, and going back would lead to an external URL outside of our app, I'd like to redirect the user to the homepage instead.

Comment: I think you might be approaching the problem incorrectly. If the user navigates to or *into* your app, and the page they are trying to access is protected, redirect to your auth page and pass the current location (*i.e. the page they are trying to access*) in route state. Once the user has authenticated, redirect back to the page they were trying to access. If the user issues a back navigation at any time here they should absolutely be allowed to get back to the page they were on previously, internal or external, whatever is in the browser's history stack.

Comment: Bit of an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)? Can you [edit] to include details for the underlying issue you are trying to resolve that you described in your comment? With this can you include a [mcve] of the relevant code a user is navigate between?